# How to avoid repetition when writting about your day?

Tags: sujet, style-de-rédaction

I would like to know how to write about your day in French but not sound too boring. I have written *je me réveille à six heures et quart, je me brosse les dents, je me douche* etc. but I am constantly saying *I this*, *I that* so please help.

Comment: How to avoid writing "je" if you're basically writing about yourself and what you did? If you did this in English I assume you'd have a lot of "I" in your text too.

Comment: Yes so I am constantly saying 'I' so that is why I asked

Answer (score 8):

Nothing forbids to omit a couple of "*je*":

"*Je me réveille à six heures et quart, me brosse les dents puis prends une douche*"

Comment: Oh I get it now so that is how you extend the sentence so it doesn't make it sound boring. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

*Je* is not what makes your writing boring. It's the way you describe the facts without emotion.

You can wake up *péniblement* ou bien *guilleret*, with a *réveille-matin* or *par le chant des merles*. Your story is less about what you do than about how you feel while doing them.

Moreover, you can insist on the boring way everything repeats day after day: *Je me lève et je te bouscule: tu ne te réveilles pas. Comme d'habitude...*

Comment: @ironman -- Le dernier paragraphe est le début d'une célèbre chanson de Claude François  ( http://www.frmusique.ru/texts/f/francois_claude/commedhabitude.htm )

Answer (score 0):

Le matin je me réveille autour de sept heures et demie et reçois une douche et nettoie mes dents il y a environ trente minutes plus tard je vais en bas manger le petit déjeuner qui est normalement des céréales après que je regarderais la télévision quitter pendant quelque temps ensuite avec mes amis depuis quelques heures après que je vais à la maison et fais sa toilette alors dînent et vont finalement au lit.

Comment: autour de sept heures -> vers sept heures, reçois une douche -> prends une douche, nettoie mes dents -> me lave les dents,  il y a environ trente minute plus tard -> et une demi-heure plus tard, je vais en bas -> je descend, manger le petit déjeuner -> prendre mon petit déjeuner, I give up for the even more broken last part...

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would include certain phrases for example: *Avant de me brosser les dents je mange mon petit déjeuner* [Before brushing my teeth I ate breakfast.]

Answer (score -3):

*Se lever a six heures le matin*. You can start like this.

Comment: This would not match the style of the following, which would require some adaptation. It is not fit for all contexts. Especially, it is seems a poor fit when describing _your_ habits. It describes habits (no one's in particular), and you probably expect a comment about it in the end. _To wake up at quarter past six, to have a shower, ... How common that all is!_